# Three.js - browser alert needed for replacing element in Object3D

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

When I want to remove element from Object3D and replace it by other element in the same place in scene I must make window alert for effect. Without alert it looks like scene isn't refreshing properly - old element is still there and new element is also rendered (or is rendered after one more element is added in the same place - some kind of delay).
Code is very simple (Bed inherits from Object3D):

```
Bed.prototype.setMattressModel = function(plik){
var tekst = 'models/' + plik;

this.remove(mattress);

var manager2 = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var obejectLoader2 = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager2);

obejectLoader2.load(tekst, this.loadMattress2);

alert(''); //without this new mattress is rendered together with old one
this.add(mattress);
}

Bed.prototype.loadMattress2 = function(object, materials){

mattress = new THREE.Mesh(object, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));

mattress.materials = materials;
mattress.scale.set(20,20,20);

}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bed.prototype.setMattressModel = function(plik){
    var tekst = 'models/' + plik;

    this.remove(mattress);

    var manager2 = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    var obejectLoader2 = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager2);

    obejectLoader2.load(tekst, this.loadMattress2.bind(this));

}

Bed.prototype.loadMattress2 = function(object, materials){

    mattress = new THREE.Mesh(object, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));

    mattress.materials = materials;
    mattress.scale.set(20,20,20);

    this.add(mattress);
}
```

I've made 2 updates:

- You should only add the mattress after you've loaded it.
- I've binded the loadMattress2 to the bed object. This makes sure that this is the bed you want to use.

Why did it work with alert?

When the alert was used then it got some time to load the mattress which in return made sure that the mattress was added.